# How to call java reflection when you don't know the parameter type

Tags: java, reflection

I want to save the parameter name, type and value in an xml file and call and set object values through reflection. For example:

```
<object type="ObjectType">
    <param name="param" type="Integer" value="500"></param>
    <param name="param2" type="BigDecimal" value="500"></param>
</object>

Class c = Class.forName("ObjectType");
Object parsedObj = c.newInstance();

Class paramClass = Class.forName("java.math.BigDecimal");
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod(attribute.getParam(), new Class[]{paramClass});

// Here is the problem, I do not know how to cast the object to correct object type.

method.invoke(parsedObj, new BigDecimal("500"));
```

If you know how to parse the object value "500" to paramClass, please help me by answering the thread.

Thanks.

Comment: The title is very misleading, because you know the parameter type. You don't know how to parse a string to an instance of the parameter type.

Comment: All Wrappers (Integer, Long, etc) have valueOf method that converts String to appropariate type, you can try to relay on this convention and see if paramClass has valueOf with String arg.

Comment: Common approach is to search for string-arg constructor, then static string-arg method with names `valueOf`, `of`, `parse`, and if exists any, call such method by reflection. In your case, both `Integer` and `BigDecimal` classes have string-arg constructors that return instance of parsed value.

Comment: but BigDecimal do not support valueOf(String) for example.

Comment: thanks Sasha, let me try String constructor and see if it works in most cases. let me know if there is another way to do it also, because in the end I may find a class which do not support string constructor. thanks.

Comment: @AthirGillani for such cases, you can add one more optional attribute to `<param>`, say, `"parseMethod"`, where name of method accepting `String` and returning parsed object, should be named. Then, if you meet this attribute in `<param>` element, just use this method instead of guessing.

Comment: thanks Sasha... really looks a workable solution...